# How to solve this differential equation with unbounded coefficient?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested in looking for solutions to the following ode,
$$u''-\frac{u'}{x} = \frac{u}{(1+x^2)^2}.$$
I tried to find an integrating factor but none of the usual techniques seem to work. Any hints/comments will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is $$u''+p(x)u' +q(x)u=0,$$ with $p(x)=-\frac{1}{x}$ and $q(x)=- \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}=-\frac{1}{(x+i)^2(x-i)^2}$. So $x=0$ is a pole of order $1$ of $p(x)$ and $x=i$ and $x=-i$ are both poles of order $2$ of $q(x)$. That is: $0, i,$ and $-i$ are all [regular singular points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point) of your equation. Also we have that, doing $t=\frac{1}{x}$, the equation becomes: $$t^2u''+3tu' - \frac{t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}u=0.$$ From wich we conclude that $\infty$ is also a regular singular point. As you can see in Kristensson's [Second Order Differential Equations](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-7020-6), chapter 4, your equation can be transformed in a [Heun's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun_function). Expressing the solutions as Heun's functions is, probably, the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a [Sturm-Liouville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory#Reduction_to_Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_form) [problem](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%27%27-u%27%2Fx%3Du%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29%5E2), in which case the best you can do is try to find a spectrum by Gram-Schmidt on the standard polynomial basis $\{x, x^2, x^3,\cdots\}$, using the corresponding [orthogonality weight](https://web.iisermohali.ac.in/Faculty/anoshjoseph/courses/2019_odd_mmp1/lec34.pdf).